# HTML5 Date type as a parameter to stored procedure in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm trying to pass a html5 input type date variable as a parameter to a stored procedure. The Query executes successfully in my php page,but the column date value in the table which the stored procedure inserts is marked as 0000-00-00.

Please tell me where i went wrong.
Thanks for Your time.

```
<?php include 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST['submitbtn'])){
$date = $_POST['datefield'];
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date));

$result = mysql_query("Call seat(".$newDate.")");

if($result == FALSE){
    echo "Sorry Query Failed!";
}
else
{
    echo "Success";
}

}
?>

<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<form method="post">
<input type="date" name="datefield"><br>
<input type="submit" name="submitbtn">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The sql fn:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `seat`(IN `dateP` VARCHAR(20))
NO SQL
begin
declare i int default 1;
while i < 250 do
insert into seat (Seat_ID,dateP) values (i,dateP);
set i = i + 1;
end while;
end
```

The seat table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `seat` (
`ID` int(100) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `Seat_ID` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `Row_ID` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
 `Col_ID` int(4) NOT NULL,
 `Amount` int(3) NOT NULL,
 `DateP` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
)
```

Comment: Also, can you show us the value of the variable that is being sent to your stored procedure? It will help in figuring out what went wrong.

Comment: You're probably NOT inserting correctly the date into the database, if you're even inserting it. Please provide us some piece of code to read? We can't predict your code :P

Comment: I'V added the code for my php page

Comment: What query are you doing here? the whole code is correct until $newDate. In fact, $newDate is outputting the date in the right format (YYYY-MM-DD). I don't really understand what your query is trying to do, though!... Since you're probably calling an SQL function, can you please provide it too? The error is surely there!

Comment: I'v added the table structure as well as sql Fn()

Comment: @Ashwin Ayyappa: I've updated the comment below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem probably is there:

```
$result = mysql_query("Call seat(".$newDate.")");
```

Please provide us the sql function you're calling.

Moreover, you're probably going wrong when you're inserting the date in your SQL function.

Please make sure that your sql function insert the date you're passing BETWEEN ' '.

If you're doing a query like:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (ID, Date) VALUES ($id, $date)")
```

It will insert 0000-00-00.

This is correct instead:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO tablename (ID, Date) VALUES ($id, '$date')")
```

Also:

Take a look at [mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php).

mysql_query is deprecated!..

EDIT:

There you are, your error probably is there! :

```
insert into seat (Seat_ID,dateP) values (i,dateP);
```

## Try this :

```
insert into seat (Seat_ID,dateP) values (i,'dateP');
```

Comment: Thanks A lot. THe prob was this ('.$date.'). I used ('$date') and voila, It was Done.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you will have to convert whatever value is in your html into a php date. after that you should be able to pass it to your stored proc, assuming that it is in a format the database can understand. See the php DateTime functions: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getdate.php

Comment: yeah... I posted this before he edited to add the source. my bad.